# Will the use case perform full or index scan in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a table user.

```
user_id   -> unique, partiton key
user_city -> primary sort key
```

Would the query perform a full scan or would it benefit from sort key?

Also, what would be results if i used gsi on user_city?

`pseudocode: fetch all user_id that have user_city="abc"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your partition key is unique, you don't need a sort key nor does having one provide any benefit.  In fact, having one is a bad idea because now your `user_id` doesn't have to be unique.  Also you'd have to use Query() to return a users information with just the `user_id`.  GetItem() would need `user_id` and `user_city`

Simply define the table with `user_id` as the primary key.
Then create a GSI with a partition key of `user_city`.

You don't even need a sort key on the GSI unless you want the data returned in a particular order.  Perhaps `user_id` or perhaps `user_name`.

Comment: So, sort key or LSI are beneficial when we don't have a unique attribute for partition key?